# Divide android layout in four columns

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'd like to divide my layout into four columns.

Here my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recivechallan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="323232"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reciveDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recivechallan"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/recivestatus"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5456455565456" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recivestatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reciveDate"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/recivebtn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ready"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recivebtn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recivechallan"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Recive" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Results**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Please suggest me how i can fix this problem

Thanks In Advance

Any Help Is Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try to use `TableLayout` with `TableRow`

example http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout as your parent container. Then set for all the TextViews and Buttons the weight as you wish, and SET THE WIDTH TO 0dp. That's important ... then it should it work :)